# SharePoint CSOM List Allow Multiple Selections on a choice Column?

Tags: list, csom, column-formatting, microsoft-graph

How can I set Allow multiple Selections to ON on a **Choice** column in SharePoint list using CSOM or Graph API? I can't seem to find a way to do it.
Here's the setting that I need to turn on.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is doable via XML.
Here is the code:
Add this XML to a file in your desktop to avoid C# string issues.

```
    <Field Type="MultiChoice" Name="SideDishesChoice" StaticName="SideDishesChoice" DisplayName="Side dishes">
  <Default>Patatoes</Default>
  <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>Fresh vegetables</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Beans</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Pepper Sauce</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>
```

Then make a CSOM call as follows:

```
 string schemaChoiceField = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myXML.txt");
 Field choiceField = List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaChoiceField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
 _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Reference: https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/